# Methods in only Collection

Tags: java

A HW question

You are given a list, L , and a another list, P, containing integers sorted in ascending order.  The operation printLots(L,P) will print the elements in L that are in positions specified by P. For instance, if P=1,3,4,6, the elements in positions 1,3,4, and 6 in L are printed.  Write the procedure printLots(L,P).  The code you provide should be the java method itself (not pseudocode), the containing class is not necessary. 
You may use only the public Collection https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html methods that are inherited by lists L and P.   You may not use methods that are only in List. Anything that the Collection methods return is fair game, so you might think about how to use iterators.

Hi all, above all is a part of a problem. I am very confused about what it means. I am not very familiar with Collection and lists. So does this requirement means that I cannot use methods such as get() and instead have to use Iterator?

Here is my code:

```
public static void printLots(List<Integer> L, List<Integer> P){
    int size = L.size;
    for(int i=0; i<P.size; i++){
        int pos = P.get(i);
        if(P.get(i) <= size){
            int val = L.get(pos);
            System.out.println(val);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("It has exceeded the number of elements in L");
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: The best way to get clarification about what your assignment means is to ask your instructor.  We can only guess what s/he meant.

Comment: You are confused about what the instructions mean... You should be asking your professor, not us. If you try to implement this and it doesn't work, **that** is when we can help.

Comment: Change `List<Integer>` to `Collection<Integer>`. Then the compiler will force you to only use methods that are in `Collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use `List.get(idx)`.

I think they are trying to get you to think about a more "interesting" way of doing it.  `Collection` does technically defined a `toArray` method that you could use, but it's probably against the spirit of the problem you have been set.

`Collection` also has a `contains` method, so you could iterate over your first list, increment a counter, and see if the second contains that index each time.  If so, print it.  It's a very inefficient way, but it would satisfy the problem.

I would suggest changing the declaration of your parameters to `Collection<Integer>` instead, that way the compiler will prevent you from accidentally using methods that exist in `List`

Comment: Thank you so much! But if I cannot use the get method, how should I get the element in a linked list given the index?

Comment: You are still allowed to use `contains`, so loop over every possible value in the list `L` using an iterator, and see if the other list contains it each time.  That doesn't need `get`, and uses an `Iterator`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that you're right and `.get(int)` is not allowed.

Since positions in `P` are given in ascending order, it's easy to use an iterator and keep a counter of the element currently "iterated at". The counter is also strictly ascending.

A "cheat" would be to use `.toArray()` and use index access in it :)